# Bundling and minification of angular2 project, Js and Html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Been working on an angular2 project for a while now, after updating it from angular1 (loving angular2 btw).

Now i would like to bundle the project, but unsure what is the best bundler to use?
Also i see some posts saying that they split the bundle into multiple files (like app.bundle.js and vendors.bundle.js) and others have 1 large file.  What is the best method?  I always throught that many files were better because browsers can download multiple files at the same time?
Do you need to use a gulp task for all this, or something else completely?

Also, how can i minify the HTML templates in an angular2 app?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Webpack or Systemjs-Builder to bundle your app. There are tons of seed projects from which you can take hints e.g. [this](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) and [this](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular2-JumpStart) and you can use [this](https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template) in your gulp task to inline the templates with your build.

Answer (score 0):

**Now i would like to bundle the project, but unsure what is the best bundler to use?**

All answers to your questions will be subjective, but it is factual that Webpack offers plugins and configuration settings to suit your needs.

**Also i see some posts saying that they split the bundle into multiple files (like app.bundle.js and vendors.bundle.js) and others have 1 large file. What is the best method?**

Splitting into multiple files is definitely the most common method.  It allows you to keep your application code separated from your dependencies, which makes debugging less of a nightmare.

The part of your Webpack config file that handles this might look something like this:

```
  // our angular app
  entry: { 'vendor': './src/vendor.ts', 'main': './src/main.ts' },

  // Config for our build files
  output: {
    path: '',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
```

**Do you need to use a gulp task for all this, or something else completely?**

If you use Webpack, then Gulp is not required at all.  I'd recommend just using NPM scripts.  Don't quote me on this, but I think Webpack can just flat out replace Gulp for Angular2 projects.

**Also, how can i minify the HTML templates in an angular2 app?**

Webpack has a [HTML minify plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minify-loader) for this.

You can use it like so:

```
loaders: [
        {
                test: /\.html$/,
                name: "mandrillTemplates",
                loader: 'raw!html-minify' // raw is another loader
        }
    ]
```